# Expo EAS build ignores background color

Tags: react-native, build, expo

In my App's package.json I have the following commands:

```
"build-android-eas": "set EAS_NO_VCS=1 && eas build --profile preview --platform android",
"build-android-old": "set EAS_NO_VCS=1 && expo build:android -t apk",
```

in the app.json I set the color:

```
"androidNavigationBar": {
  "backgroundColor":"#363636"
}
```

Both build commands are executing successfully, but results are different:

[image]

i.e. in the EAS-APK the nav-bar keeps the default white bg-color, whereas the older expo-APK produces the expected result.

What am I missing?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I quote my workaround here from https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/13062

I added `"expo-navigation-bar": "^1.3.0"` to my dependencies, and call it in the main "App" component:

```
export default () => {
  useEffect( _ => {
    const prepare = async _ => {
        NavigationBar.setBackgroundColorAsync( '#363636' )
        
        await SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync()
    }

    prepare()
  }, [] )

  // some code
}
```

Optically it shows the default (white) color of the NavBar on SplashScreen, then in approx 500 ms repaints it to the color I need and remains the same for the rest of the app.

BTW, If if call `NavigationBar.getBackgroundColorAsync()` just before the setter, it returns the correct color which is defined in app.json. That color has no effect though.

Maybe it will help somebody for now...